# Why cant I change the display of my html table to 'block' using the jquery and the table id

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a jinja template that receives a list of twitter status' and their replies. The original tweets are listed to the left, and their replies in dynamically generated tables to the right, each with the conversation_id as the id of the table. When an original tweet is clicked, it should should change the display of the replies (using the conversation id) to 'block' I have tried various methods to display but none work for that function.  The loader works fine so I suspect it might be something to do with how the id variable is passed to the JS function, but I really don't know. If I set the display to 'block' on the replies-table, the replies all show so I know the data is all being loaded.

Here is the code for the template.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div id="loader-container">
    <div id="loader"></div>
    <div id="loader-text" class="text-center">
        <h4>Downloading conversations, please be patient.</h4>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="content">
    <div class="container m-3">
        <h1 class="text-center">Download Twitter Conversations</h1>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <form class="form" action="{{  url_for('download_conversations')  }}" method="post">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div>Twitter Handle</div>
                <div class="row">
                    <input type="text" name="screen-name" id="screen-name" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div>Conversation Count</div>
                <div class="row">
                    <input type="text" name="count" id="count" min="1" max="100" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 p-3">
                <button class="btn" type="sumbit" onclick="loading();">Get Conversations</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col shadow-lg">
            <table class="table table-dark text_white">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Handle</th>
                    <th scope="col">Tweet</th>
                    <th scope="col">Replies Count</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody >
                    {%  if conversations != None  %}
                    {%  for c in conversations  %}
                    <a href="">
                        <tr onclick="showReplies({{  c.conversation_id  }})" style="user-select: none;">
                            <td>{{  c.screen_name  }}</td>
                            <td>{{  c.original_text  }}</td>
                            <td>{{  c.replies | length  }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </a>
                    {%  endfor  %}
                    {%  endif  %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="col shadow-lg">
            {%  if conversations != None  %}
                {%  for c in conversations  %}
                    {%  if c.replies != None  %}
                        <table class="table table-dark text_white replies-table" id="{{  c.conversation_id  }}">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="col">Handle</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Tweet</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody >
                                {%  for r in c.replies  %}                                              
                                    <tr style="user-select: none;">
                                        <td>{{  r.screen_name  }}</td>
                                        <td>{{  r.text  }}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                {%  endfor  %}
                            </tbody>
                        </table>                        
                    {%  endif  %}
                {%  endfor  %}
            {%  endif  %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
    function loading(){
        $("#content").hide(); 
        $("#loader").show();
        $("#loader-text").show();
              
    }
// ]]></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showReplies(id){
        $("replies-table").hide(); 
        id = '#'.concat(id.toString())
        $(id).style.display = "block";          
    }
</script>
{%  endblock  %}
```

and the only css fo the replies-table

```
 .replies-table{
    display: none;
  }
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Table should be turned into `display: table`. With jquery it should work like this

```
$(id).css({display: "table"})
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and it didn't solve it. The issue seems to be the variable used for the id. The ID is a twitter conversation_id which consists of only numbers, which I believe should be fine with html5. I tried with just the ID and also concatenating the 'convo-' with the id so it looks like 'convo-123456778' but I keep getting the error message: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: '#convo-1349733008081879040'

Comment: I enclosed the curly brackets {{}} in quotation marks which solved the above particular error, but still the selector is still not working. If I attempt x = document.getelementbyid(id), and print x, it is showing as null, so it appears as though it is something to do with the id. If I change the code and put an id directly in $(id).css({display: "table"}), then it works fine.

Comment: Good, document.getElementById("#id") wont work, it has to be document.getElementById("id") (without hash)

Answer (score 0):

I never got round to finding out why it never worked, although I'm sure it was a problem with the selector name being a variabe, and possibly all numbers. Either way, it was solved by getting rid of the jQuery for that particular statement and just using document.getelementByID and then x.style.display = 'block'

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showReplies(id){
    $(".replies-table").css("display", "none"); // Need the leading "." to select by class name
    x = document.getElementById(id)
    x.style.display='block'
}
</script>
```